# Expressing errors in a percentage value

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis

This is probably a stupid question but I can't find an answer to it.

I have a percentage value X% for which there is an associated measurement error of Y% e.g. 50% of dogs ±10% love cats. How should this be expressed?

50% ±10.
50 ±10% or
50% ±10%

Comment: What does 50%$\pm$10% mean? The value can range from 40% to 60% or 45% to 55%?

Answer (score 2):

Your second answer, maybe even more clear like this: $(50\pm10)\%$

(If it helps, think that if you chose to express it in fractions, it would be $0.5\pm0.1$.)